# Amending permissions to bash files on Airflow Composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer, airflow

We are running Airflow on Google Cloud Composer.

I have a bash script that is being called in a BashOperator of my DAG:

```
split_files = BashOperator(
    task_id='split_gcp_files',
    bash_command='/home/airflow/gcs/dags/file_splitter.sh ',
    xcom_push=True,
    depends_on_past=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

When I run this however, I get the following error:

```
[2021-06-17 18:24:13,330] {bash_operator.py:137} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmp8dsdf38/split_gcp_filesah83sdf
[2021-06-17 18:24:13,330] {bash_operator.py:147} INFO - Running command: /home/airflow/gcs/dags/file_splitter.sh 
[2021-06-17 18:24:13,472] {bash_operator.py:154} INFO - Output:
[2021-06-17 18:24:13,475] {bash_operator.py:158} INFO - /tmp/airflowtmp8dsdf38/split_gcp_filesoofibpg7: line 1: /home/airflow/gcs/dags/file_splitter.sh: Permission denied
```

The file_splitter.sh has been copied to a GCS bucket, but I'm not sure where the file is located for Airflow to amend the permissions? E.g. where do I find '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/'?

I've tried SSH-ing into the Kubernetes nodes but couldn't find that path or perhaps I don't have permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the bash command to this worked, any ideas why?:

```
bash_command='bash /home/airflow/gcs/dags/file_splitter.sh '
```

Comment: The reason is because you have not execution permissions over the script. Using `bash` you only need read permissions and therefore you do not get the `Permission denied` error.

Refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203371/run-script-sh-vs-bash-script-sh-permission-denied for more details and context.